# Why cannot I post this question?

Tags: support

I don't understand why I cannot post this question: "How can a student protect his or her intellectual work when sending a research proposal to an unknown professor?".

The website informs that it doesn't respect quality standards but, since I cannot get what is wrong with this question, my impression is that some users put some restrictions to me. May it be and is it fair, regardless from the content of the question?

PS. Furthermore, the website doesn't give any indication regarding what is wrong and how to improve it.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your question?  Usually there is more information about context and circumstance in a question, and the system might be flagging it as "too short" and therefore likely to be closed.

Comment: I continue not to understand this community. What I should tell more? What kind of context should be added? There isn't any circumstance. That is the question and it is a clear question. Moreover, if clarity is present, as in this case, brevity should be appreciated.

Comment: Some things that I would want to know in order to answer such a question: What type of intellectual work are you concerned about: manuscripts, ideas, datasets, something else?  Why are you sending it to the professor: are you looking for help, trying to get admitted to a PhD program, something else?  Why this particular professor: did somebody refer you to them, did you just Google some keywords, is your work based on their work?  These sorts of things will strongly affect the answer to the question.

Comment: @Alwayslearning: If the _system_ is not letting you post the question, that's a different matter than the community closing a question. We don't have any real input on the backend software, so we can't help when the system balks at or complains about a question.

Comment: Without further detail, the question you are trying to ask sounds like a duplicate of [When applying for a new job or fellowship, how to protect your ideas from being stolen by the lab you are applying to?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63226/when-applying-for-a-new-job-or-fellowship-how-to-protect-your-ideas-from-being) anyways

Comment: and on the above referenced question, a related question is answered about 'intellectual theft': http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27472/is-there-any-research-on-the-prevalence-of-academic-theft